# How to manage packets in a custom server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, server, system.net

**Context:**

I want to make a multiplayer game with unity and i would like to make dedicated servers for players to be able to open their own server. I haven't made the game yet, i'm just experimenting with my server and a test client. The server is a C# console using System.Net (as the client for now). For now i just want to make a nice architecture for the future real server.

**Problem:**

In a game, i would assume there is a lot of different types of packets that the player can send and receive to/from the server. And i'm trying to find a scalable/clean way to manage them. But as you can imagine it's not going so well...

**How does it work right now:**

For now when the client want to send data to the server it sends it this way:

*[PacketCode]Message*

Where: **PacketCode** -> is a code i defined for every type of packet
and **Message** -> is just a string for now

When the server receive the message it call the *Filter* method from *HandleReceivedPackage* (code down below)
then it process the data and if needed send the information it needs.

Here is the class on the server that handle all the different package:

```
using Server.Utilities;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
    public static class HandleReceivedPacket
    {
        public static void Filter(TcpClient client, Stream stream, string data)
        {
            int code = int.Parse(data[1].ToString());
            string message = data.Substring(3);

            ServerLogger.Log($"Received data from client: [{code}]: {message}", LogLevel.Info);

            switch (code)
            {
                default:
                    Server.SendToClient(stream, PacketType.MESSAGE, "Message sent, but it's not a comand... Nothing happenned.");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Server.SendToClient(stream, PacketType.TEST, "");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Server.SendToClient(stream, PacketType.MESSAGE, "");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Server.DisconnectClient(client);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the class on the client that handle all the different package:**

```
namespace ClientTest
{
    public static class HandleReceivedPacket
    {
        public enum PacketType
        {
            TEST = 0,
            MESSAGE = 1,
            DISCONNECT = 2
        }

        public static void Filter(string data)
        {
            int code = int.Parse(data[1].ToString());
            string message = data.Substring(3);

            switch (code)
            {
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Message sent, but it's not a comand... Nothing happenned.");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection: OK");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Your message have been received");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected !");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**

So, with my actual method I could have 500 case in my switch (x2 since the server as to have the same) and my enum would be gigantic...

My question is:

**Is there a better way of managing all these packets and how would you do it if you had to do it ?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `handlers[code](message);`

Comment: First of all I would go binary (`byte[]`) instead of strings .. it's more expensive to transmit and doing string parsing than directly operate with byte conversion ... then you could have an `enum` to define the message (if it is less than 256 different types it is basically a single `byte`) this way you can make your switch case - which imho is totally fine to use

Comment: For a multiuser I wrote once I had a message protocol like `uint senderId, byte serviceID, byte message, byte[] content` .. where `service` and `message` are basically before mentioned single byte indices for selecting the handling service and message .. then within the message handler the handling method is responsible for converting the received `byte[]` into according type  .. prefixed entire message length as prefix header and used `BitConverter` to extract expected types while moving forward the index ;)

Comment: Yeah i'm already using byte[] to transmit but i convert it to string in another function before this one, sorry I should have mentionned it...  But if i understand correctly you are converting once you know the code ? But i like this way it seems more straight forward :) I hoped for something else than the switch but i'll try your way, thanks !